# asp.net mvc 4 default model binder is setting certain values to 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form which is posting to an Edit controller action and the default model binder is setting some values to 0 erroneously. The model being used is a complex model (multiple objects inside it), but I do not think his is the issue because I tried filling just one of the objects inside in it's own model and had the same issue. Also bizarre is that other properties are being populated without an issue.

[image]

As you can see from the image, Request.Form["Pricelist.PricelistId"] is posting a value of 3, but if you look at the model property inside the _adminEditPricelistVM.Pricelist.PricelistId = 0.

This is the ViewModel:

```
public class adminEditPricelistVM
{
    public Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; } //holds the current pricelist

    public List<adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVM> PPPVMs { get; set; } //this is the model that contains a Product object and a PricelistProduct object  PPPVMs = PPPVMs

    public List<PricingFormula> PricingFormulas { get; set; } // this will be populated by all the PricingFormulas that apply to this pricelist

    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } //this will be used to filter the PPPVMs and the PricingFormulas by category in the view
}
```

This is some of the HTML (very standard, here):

```
<form action="/pricelist/edit/3" method="post">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Pricelist ID must be a number." data-val-required="The Pricelist ID field is required." id="Pricelist_PricelistId" name="Pricelist.PricelistId" type="hidden" value="3" />
```

The only thing worth mentioning is that I am using non sequential indexed for the collection items inside the Pricelist object. A Pricelist contains a list of PricelistProducts and PricelistProducts contains a list of PricelistProductOptions and PricelistProductOptions contains a list of PricelistProductOptionsDetails. These are formatted in the HTML as folows:

```
<input id="Pricelist_PricelistProducts_Index" name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts.Index"     type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="Pricelist_PricelistProducts_1__PricelistId" name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts[1].PricelistId" type="hidden" value="3" />                        

<input checked="checked" id="1" name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts[1].ProductId" onclick="toggleProductChkBx(this,1)" type="checkbox" value="1" /><input name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts[1].ProductId" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input id="Pricelist_PricelistProducts_Index" name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts.Index" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="Pricelist_PricelistProducts_2__PricelistId" name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts[2].PricelistId" type="hidden" value="3" />                        

<input id="2" name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts[2].ProductId" type="checkbox" value="2" /><input name="Pricelist.PricelistProducts[2].ProductId" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

I'm not sure what else I can add. I look forward to your responses!

Comment: ASP.NET MVC default ModelBinder looks for HTML Ids in the request that match properties names to build the model back in the server. How did you generate this HTML? Html Helpers?

Comment: Id's? really? I did not know that. I mimicked the names thinking this was sufficient. Thanks. I will give that a go.

Comment: Actually after reviewing my code, the PricelistId which is returning 0 instead of 3 does have the proper ID. It looks like:<input id="Pricelist_PricelistId" type="hidden" value="3" name="Pricelist.PricelistId" data-val-required="The Pricelist ID field is required." data-val-number="The field Pricelist ID must be a number." data-val="true">

Comment: I've been doing some research and it looks as though the model binder use the Request.Form values to populate. This website, http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx, shows model binding examples of forms that do not even have IDs. Are you certain this is the case?

Comment: Yep, Default ModelBinder looks into Request.Form for IDs that match thein model properties to build the object back in the server! Yours object its kinda complex, so i think that you will need a custom Model Binder: take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fals. The problem actually turned out to be my own stupidity (as usual). I had a [Read Only] attribute on that property in my domain model so the setter was not working.